# Proibir a inserção de dados repetidos

Tags: php, html

Eu preciso que ao digitar um texto em um input no formulário, ele valide ali mesmo se já existe este registro, que mostre o resultado pro usuário e que não permita enviar o formulário sem alterar o que está repetido.

formulario e js:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="php/cadastro.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Descrição</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" id="descricao" required="required">
  </div>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ 
      $("input[name='descricao']").on('exit', function(){
        var descricao = $(this).val();
        $.get('arquivo.php?descricao=' + descricao, function(data){ 
          $('#resultado').html(data);
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

arquivo.php

```
<?php
  $conexao   = mysqli_connect('', '', '', ''); 
  $descricao = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'descricao');
  $sql       = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao = '{$descricao}'";
  $query     = $mysqli->query( $sql ); 
  if( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {
    echo 'Já existe!';
  } else {
    echo 'Não existe ainda!';
  }
?>
```

Eu gostaria que não fosse através de um arquivo a verificação, que verificasse com php no próprio form e já mostrasse para o usuário já perceber que não poderá utilizar tal descricão, sem ter que ir pra outro arquivo buscar os registro e voltar para a página.

arquivo de envio pro banco:

```
$conexao          = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
$descricao        = $_POST['descricao'];

$sql            = "INSERT INTO tabela(descricao) VALUES ('$descricao')";
```

Se alguém tiver sugestões, agradeço.

Comment: Terá que fazer a verificação via ajax no evento blur do input, essa é a maneira mais básica, qual seu código?

Comment: Ok, poste o código que você já tem e qual é a saída que o mesmo gera. Se for algum erro, poste a mensagem de erro também.

Comment: Ok, irei postar o que tenho, mas anteriormente tentei utilizar ajax baseado em algumas pesquisas, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma bem simples de implementar esse comportamento seria utilizando **listeners** sobre o `input` e executando uma consulta via ajax ao servidor para validar a existência da **descrição** no banco de dados. Você pode ter uma página com o seguinte código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .message {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="cadastro.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" id="descricao" required="required">
                <br/>
                <span class="message"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#descricao').on('change paste keyup', function () {
                    var messageSpan = $('.message');
                    $.get({
                        url: '/valida_descricao.php',
                        data: {'descricao': $(this).val()}
                    }).done(function () {
                        messageSpan.text('Descrição aceita!');
                        messageSpan.css('display', 'inline');
                    }).fail(function () {
                        messageSpan.text('Descrição não aceita!');
                        messageSpan.css('display', 'inline');
                    });
                });
        </script>     
    </body>
</html>
```

... e um script php chamado **valida_descricao.php** para a validação:

```
<?php
// Obtendo o valor da variável
$descricao = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'descricao');

// Conectando ao banco de dados
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'test');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao = '{$descricao}'";
$query = $conexao->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows > 0 || empty($descricao)) {
        // Define HTTP Status Code para 403 (HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden)
        http_response_code(403);
} else {
        // Define HTTP Status Code para 200 (HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
        http_response_code(200);
}
```

O fluxo do código javascript no final da página será controlado de acordo com o HTTP Status Code definido na resposta do servidor. E é isso.

Alguns dos conceitos, técnicas e ferramentas utilizadas nessa implementação: [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)); [HTTP Status Code](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html); [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).